# Existence of a certain norm on space of measurable functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a measure space with measure $\mu$. Given a strictly increasing continuous (or sufficiently nice) function $\phi:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ with $\phi(0)=0$. Is it true that we can find a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on the space of measurable functions (or at least a subspace of "sufficiently nice" functions) satisfying the following two conditions?

1. $\|f\|\le \|g\|$ if $|f|\le |g|$ (pointwise).
2. $\|\chi_A\|=\phi(\mu(A))$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function.

Such a norm seems to be constructible by integrals if $\phi$ is simple. E.g. $\phi(u)=\sqrt{u+u^2}$, we can take $\|f\|=\sqrt{(\int_X |f|d\mu)^2+\int_X |f|^2 d\mu}$. But otherwise I am stuck. If this is not true in general, what conditions on $\phi$ can we ensure such an existence?

Comment: I think at a minimum you need $\phi$ to be concave.  For instance consider $\phi(t) = t^2$.  If we take $X =\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure, we would have to have $\|\chi_{[0,1)} + \chi_{[1,2]}\| = \|\chi_{[0,2]}\| = 4 > 2 = \|\chi_{[0,1)}\| + \|\chi_{[1,2]}\|$ contradicting the triangle inequality for the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is known as a **symmetric** (or rearrangement invariant) Banach space of measurable functions (not to be confused with Riemannian symmetric spaces) and the associated **fundamental function**, see the recent book [Foundations of symmetric spaces of measurable functions](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3525091) by Rubshtein et al. For instance, the **Lorentz** Banach spaces are the ones that correspond to concave functions $\phi$ with $\phi(0)=0$.